# Connecting SQL-Server directly to online Database rails activerecord-sqlserver-adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, database-connection

I have just installed both the gems which mentioned in [`README.md][1]` file. I have a query string and I want to connect to the database directly from localhost.. is it possible?

```
class Timelapse < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection({
    :adapter  => "sqlserver",
    :host     => "myhostname.net",
    :username => "myusername",
    :password => "mypassword",
    :database => "mydbname"
  })
end
```

and I went to `rails c` tried to do `Timelapse.first` and got an error which is

```
TinyTds::Error: Adaptive Server connection failed
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/tiny_tds-0.7.0/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:74:in `connect'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/tiny_tds-0.7.0/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:74:in `initialize'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:311:in `new'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:311:in `dblib_connect'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:302:in `connect'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:58:in `initialize'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.10/lib/active_record/sqlserver_base.rb:17:in `new'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.10/lib/active_record/sqlserver_base.rb:17:in `sqlserver_connection'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/querying.rb:39:in `find_by_sql'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:639:in `exec_queries'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:515:in `load'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:243:in `to_a'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:630:in `inspect'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect like this by using these Gem

setp:- 1
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'

and also check with git [activerecord-sqlserver-adapter](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter)

step:-2
development:
  port: 1433
  mode: dblib
  adapter: sqlserver
  host:  # used when dataserver is blank
  database: 
  username: 
  password: 
  timeout: 0

default
  port: 1433 # default is 1433
  default
  mode: dblib
  dataserver: 
  timeout: 5000 
  timeout: 0 - to have no timeout
  azure: true
  dsn: